# Hot Spring Homicides - the unlucky 5

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking, story, mystery

(*Warning: Heavy reading incoming, you may want to take notes. You have been warned*)

It's the year 2157, and you're one of the few people who didn't leave earth twenty seven years ago. Why? A deadly disease overtook the planet, and you happen to have immunity. There are now less than ten million people on the planet - the rest have either died, or left on a voyage to find a new planet to colonize.

The last vacation you took seven years ago ended up turning into a [sabotage at sea](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12732/sabotage-at-sea-cursed-cruise-liner) involving multiple deaths and a theft, so you're not too keen on taking another vacation anytime soon. However, your boss is again forcing you to use your vacation days or lose them - so you decide to take a trip to Canada this time, and enjoy some hot bathing at Harrison Hot Springs in British Columbia. Perhaps there, you'll be able to have a quieter, more peaceful time.

The Agassiz-Rosedale Highway turns into Hot Springs Road as you drive closer and closer to the springs. Entering the town reveals that the town is quite deserted now, and many of the houses are starting to break down after almost thirty years of being unused. Nevertheless, you're determined to finally have a good time, and end up driving all the way to the Harrison Lakeview Resort, where you've got a room booked.

You pull in and park on the side, before heading into the building. Walking up to the front desk, an android installed behind the desk waves at you. Her smooth android voice resonates throughout the room as she says, "Welcome to the Harrison Lakeview Resort - the only operating resort in this town. Do enjoy your stay, your key is- is- is- " the android stutters, eyes fluttering. Her palms are oily, springs weak, joints are rusty. There's grease leaking onto her body already, the mechanic was thrifty. Some smoke puffs out of the back of her neck, and her lights turn out.

"Well, that was unexpected," comes a voice from under the counter. A few short moments later, a male with a green mohawk stands up from behind the counter, and places a holographic wrist brace on the counter, before hunching over the android. He looks to be lacking sleep, extremely worn out and tired.

"Who are you?" you ask.

"I'm the mechanic and owner of this resort. The name is Bob. I like to build all sorts of things, especially robots, so my friends all call me the builder. You'll find that a majority of the resort is automated with robots that I've built." He tosses you a key, which you catch. "Your room number is on the key." The number etched into the key is number 406, and you head up with your luggage to unpack.

Once you've reached the 4th floor, you look around for your room, but it seems that this floor hasn't been kept very well, and the room numbers are mostly falling off or missing, so you start trying doors. However, as soon as you try your key with the first door, you hear a new android voice emanate from the key. "You are trying to access room 403. Access is forbidden with this key. The room matching this key is 3 doors to your right." With that, you walk towards the indicated door and enter your own room and start unpacking.

By the time you've finished unpacking, the sky has already darkened, and you're feeling hungry, so you head back downstairs to look for Bob. You find him working on a robot you don't recognize - he seems to be fitting the robot with some extra small hands. "Where do I go to get food around here?" you ask.

"Only the Old Settler Pub is still open for business around these parts. Best go there if you're feeling famished," Bob replies. As you head out the door, Bob asks you, "Have you seen my android control brace? It was here earlier today, but now I can't find it." You haven't seen it, as you've been unpacking, and you inform him thus. "Ah, okay, I guess." he replies, as he returns to his work on the robot.

It's a only a three minute walk to the Pub, and as you enter, you see some familiar faces. "Could it be? Jack, Jerome, and Julian?" Three heads turn, and three jaws drop as they recognize you. It's been 7 years since you last saw the biker gang trio from the cruise ship you sailed on during your last vacation.

"Oh, you know these three? Any friend of the J's is a friend of mine," the bartender says. He's well built, and looks very strong. "I'm Andrew Gilbert Mills, but most people just call me Andrew." Making friends with the bartender, you spend some time catching up with the three of them, and get some grub. Your professional detective questioning skills helps you find out that the J's live near here and come every couple of years. You find out that they're staying in the same resort as you, in room 404, and that the resort provides them with access to tools and materials required for them to work on their bikes. You learn that the bartender is married, and that he's usually a nice guy. He's not a nice guy when people make trouble in his pub, and apparently there's been a tourist by the name of Chris making trouble in the pub. Chris isn't in the pub at the time, but your instincts and observational skills tell you that the 3 J's and Andrew, as well as the people who overheard the conversation in the pub all despise Chris. Probing a bit more seems to depict Chris as hating Andrew as well, since Andrew throws him out of the pub for making trouble all the time.

As the night sets in, and you finish your food, you decide to head back to sleep. The three minute walk back to the resort is short but quiet, until you get close to the resort itself, where you happen to overhear bits of a conversation between Bob and a balding, brown haired man who you can only seem to figure is Chris through the context of the conversation.

```
Bob: "The cost will be [inaudible] very difficult [inaudible]"
Chris: "[inaudible] Compensated [inaudible], need [inaudible], the owner. [inaudible] help?"
Bob: "[inaudible] lost it today [inaudible] try to find [inaudible]"
```

You approach quietly, sneakily, and catch a glimpse of Chris handing Bob what seems to be a credit card. Bob then fiddles around with something behind the counter, and hands a room key to Chris, before turning around to do other stuff. As Chris turns to leave, you catch a glimpse of an android control brace being placed into his pocket.

The next 2 days pass by peacefully, and you manage to get some good rest. On the second night, you wake up to the loud swearing of Bob downstairs, but the sound disappears quickly and you manage to get back to sleep after that. The third morning, however, you wake up to the sound of sirens passing by. You get up, and as quickly as you can, follow the sirens, which have stopped in front of the pub. You walk into the already roped off crime scene, your detective license getting you past the cops and into the building, and you head upstairs, towards the sound of people talking. As you arrive up top, you see that Andrew is dead in his bed. The room smells of brake fluid, and talking with the paramedics confirms that Andrew has died of brake fluid consumption. The cops are in there collecting evidence, and you see there's no brake fluid bottle anywhere in the room. You're informed that Andrew died at approximately 3AM. You also notice one of the cops picking up some light brown hairs and some green hairs from the ground, and placing them into bags, which you immediately notice as weird since Andrew is bald.

Taking note of the incident, you decide to be the bearer of bad news and tell the 3 J's about their dead friend. You enter the resort again, and walk towards their room, only to find that the door to 404 is slightly ajar and that the 3 J's are nowhere to be found. The bed looks unmade, and their luggage is all still in the room, as are their leather jackets. However, their leather jackets stink of brake fluid and motor oil. Where could they have gone?

It's at this moment that you realize that you haven't seen any androids this morning, which is weird since usually an android greets you every morning as you exit the resort. Fearing the worst, you alert the authorities and they begin a search in the small town for the 4 missing persons.

It's just past 2PM when you find Bob's body floating in a corner of one of the hot springs. He has an android control brace strapped to his arm, two out of three of the straps buckled. Some minor post mortem bruising is on the arm under the brace, and he seems to have died of drowning. There are signs that he was punched at least two or three times before death, and his knuckles are slightly bruised, as if he had fought back. There's some brown hair under his nails, a similar shade to those found at Andrew's pub. After some analysis, you determine that his time of death was around 11 hours ago.

Some more hours pass, and eventually the police give you a call, telling you that the 3 J's have been found. You head to the scene, a dark alleyway, and see the bodies 3 J's slewn across the ground, as well as the android with small hands Bob was working on before. The android has a bloody pole sticking out of its chest, and several deep dents on the head, evident that somebody was striking it with something cylindrical. Upon examination of the bodies, you determine that Julian and Jerome were killed by the android's tiny hands crushing their windpipes. Jack has a small hole in his stomach - it seems that he bled out, but not before he decommissioned the android that attacked them. The three of them died around 3 AM as well.

For the rest of the day, you talk to the the masses to try and find more information while investigating the town. You discern the following:

- Andrew used to be part of a gang
- Andrew's wife doesn't seem sad as she should be to see him die
- Chris is currently in custody due to everyone saying he was Andrew's only notable enemy, but he refuses to say anything until his lawyer arrives

## The question remains: What happened? A correct answer will be marked when someone finds the correct killer(s), motive(s), and timing of events in the story.

### Bonus: Whoever first lists all 5 of the intentional references to things that I made will be awarded a small bounty later.

Hints:

- Somebody is being framed.
- The android is not sentient and cannot make decisions - it can only be controlled
- Bob **actually did** lose his control brace. You saw Chris stealing it from where Bob lost it.
- Other than Andrew and his wife, there were no other romantic relationships - and even that relationship isn't relative to the case itself.

Comment: I like the Eminem reference - too bad the android receptionist didn't have spaghetti ;)

Comment: @n_palum shhhh save it for an answer ;) don't just give away 1 part of the 5 bonus references XD

Comment: I only found one reference (i think of them as one) or are several?

Comment: @DrnglVrgs There are 5 separate references, but that's just the bonus... try not to focus on the bonus too much lol

Comment: "dissapears" - deliberate?

Comment: "approximiately", too. And "wierd". And "the bodies 3 Js"

Comment: @Donnelle Sorry, spelling errors. I've fixed them.

Comment: I went to the previous puzzle to see if you mentioned what colour hair the 3Js have.  You describe them as bald, but then later describe them as having "bed hair"!  Is it relevant here?

Comment: @Donnelle Err... I must've missed that in my previous puzzle. Inconsistencies in the other puzzles I've made are not relevant to this one; They are purely referential links for laughs/story purposes.

Comment: I took notes reading through it in attempts to take a legitimate crack at it.. but as of right now it seems vague and you could possibly swing the answer a few ways... I'll post an actual answer if I come up with something  conclusive.

Comment: @n_palum could you let me know which parts have possible differences? I think you're right and I may have screwed up on the puzzle a bit, but as the maker of the puzzle, it's kind of hard for me to figure out which parts I left out....

Comment: @Aify I don't know that there are differences, there just seems to be concrete or justifiable information lacking. If you want to give another push/make it easier, I would recommend putting the useful/important parts of the story into a quote block so it stands out... Having to dig through that much info with almost half of it being flavor/useless, makes people not want to read it/you can miss things.. and as an anecdote, giving hints that are just telling us things we can deduce eventually in the story aren't more help to solving the puzzle.

Answer (score 5):

My theory in progress:

> Bob is having an affair with Andrew's wife. This is why he looks so tired, and why she doesn't seem too sad. There are green hairs in Andrew's room because Bob with the green mohawk has been there with Andrew's wife.
>
>  There are brown hairs in Andrew's room as well, which come from Chris, the balding brown-haired man. Bob has got him to help kill Andrew, because Andrew is strong, and given him a control brace in order to help.

References:

> Eminem (palms etc)
>  Trump (small hands)
>  Andrew Gilbert Mills (TV show, Sword Art Online)
>  Bob, a.k.a "the Builder"
>  Room 404, not found, and Room 403, access denied (HTTP status codes)

Comment: What about the 403 access forbidden?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure how we are supposed to deduce their motives as we are lacking useful information, especially after hints contradict some of the things that would make sense.

The only characters we know of in the story besides ourselves are: Chris, Bob, J's, Andrew and his wife.

We are told someone is being framed for the murder (Chris being in custody) and the only other person alive besides us is Andrew's wife which means it has to be her, or at least she told Chris to do it. The only motives we can think of, since she was not mourning, are that she disliked his gang association/friendly with Js, or she was having an affair with Chris. We know no other information about her to make any other conclusions.

However, part of me thinks that by "someone being framed" it could not mean Chris did it, but the whole Bob having the bracelet on is Bob being framed. In which case I would again assume is motivated by a dislike for Andrew and again potentially an affair with the wife.

As pointed out by other answers, Andrew was killed via brake fluid consumption, likely forced by an android. The hair found in there suggests Chris was there controlling the robot as we know he had the brace, and Bob could have either been involved, or Bob actually died first and the hair was on Chris and managed to end up in Andrew's room. Bob did fight back after all and he was dead around the same time. I am leaning towards Bob dying first and Chris going back to plant the brace when the rest was done, fighting back leading to Bob's hair ending up in Andrew's room makes sense.

The J's as we know fought the android, and they died last since they took the android with them. We know that Chris had the brace and likely ordered the attacks.

**Side notes & Observations:**

- The framing hint is vague as I pointed out in my answer.
- Stating the brace is gone does not help as this is obviously stated in the story.
- Telling us the android isn't sentient does not help as we know the brace is what controls them.
- You say that Andrew and his wife's relationship is irrelevant, so why not just leave it out, which would make Chris the only living suspect which ends the story simply.
- There is a LOT of unnecessary text in the story that makes it hard to follow because so much of it seems like useless information, which it is.

Donnelle has already listed all of the references as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt:

> First, Chris (or possibly Andrew's wife) wanted to kill Andrew. Motive? Might be related to Andrew's history of being in a gang, when he may have had some conflict with Chris. Chris could also be involved with Andrew's wife, seeing how she wasn't very affected by her husband's death. The reason Chris stayed silent could be because he wanted to protect Andrew's wife, who may have been involved with the planning, or even the actual killing.
>
>  **How was Andrew killed?**
>
>  Chris borrowed Bob's android control brace to command the android with small hands to steal some brake fluid from the bikers. Then, he and Bob forced Andrew to drink the fluid, thus killing him. The evidence is the brown (Chris') and green (Bob's) hair found in Andrew's room.
>
>  **How were the 3 J's killed?**
>
>  Evidently, by the android. The 3 J's stumbled upon the android stealing their brake fluid, then got in a fight with it, and were killed.
>
>  **How was Bob killed?**
>
>  Chris killed him. They got into a fight after killing Andrew. My theory is that they found out that the 3 J's were killed by the android by accident, and that wasn't part of their plan. Chris killed Bob, then tried to frame the murder of the 3 J's onto Bob by putting the android control brace back onto his arm. In a hurry, Chris only buckled 2 out of 3 straps.

I admit some of it may seem like a stretch, but this is the best I can do for now...

Comment: Nice try! Unfortunately, not correct. I've added a new hint :)

Answer (score 1):

Well That was a good one, a little harder than the cursed cruise liner! But here is my try:

Behind the scenes:

> 1- At first I thought that Bob made a new brace for himself, but that's not written so I didn't work on that idea
>  2-I changed my theory in order to satisfy the hint that says that somebody is being framed.

The Events:

1- The murder of Andrew:

> Chris helped his gang to kill Andrew but he didn't actually commit the crime, he stole the brace for them, used it to control the android and stole the Fluid from the 3 J's, Then the gang - without Chris- made a visit to Andrew and forced him to drink it, and of cource Andrew died
>
> Chris had a fight earlier with Andrew and he was unlucky so he left hair on the ground, or his gang framed him for whatever reason!

The motive:

> Andrew was a very important member in his gang or he crossed lines with one member of the gang.

2- The murder of Bob:

> Bob was just chatting with Andrew, but when he left he saw the gang that wanted to kill Andrew, he tried to defend his life but one of them killed him, while the others entered the pub.

The motive:

> He was just collateral

The murder of the 3 J's:

> as they were hanging out late they the gang leaving the pub, they noticed them and decided that they might witness against them, so they were killed. and then the gang destroyed the android and any evidence with it

The motive:

> To not let the 3 J's witness against them.

Extra:

> If I were a real detective I would surely see if Chris had any bruises and compare them with Bob's hand

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a stretch (and probably not complete).

> I believe the original plan was for Chris to kill Andrew with Bob's help, framing the J's for it, and then kill the J's for reasons of gang rivalry (I think Chris is in a rival gang to Andrew's/J's) while making it seem that it was an inside gang dispute, but only told Bob about Andrew.

> Based on their conversation, my interpretation is that Chris is trying to get Bob to help him kill Andrew, and therefore Bob tells him that has a high cost and difficulty (I think "the owner" part refers to the owner(s) of room 404, but I'm not 100% sure). Bob then gives him the key to Room 404 (J's room) for purposes of retrieving the brake fluid and therefore to frame them, but given that Chris steals the brace, Bob is under the impression that Andrew's murder will be committed by him and Chris personally (no androids were in the equation to Bob).

> Andrew was first to die. Chris with the key and with the help of the first android (to not bring suspicion on himself, he already stole the brace, which he later discarded as to not be found with it) retrieves the brake fluid at some point before 3 AM the second night (and probably scare the J's away from their room) and with Bob's help restrains Andrew and forces him to consume the brake fluid. While doing this, pieces of their hair manage to get on the floor.

> Soon after, on their way back to the resort, Chris decides it's time to kill the J's and straps on the brace corresponding to the "small hands" android. At this point, Bob is surprised and angry that this was omitted in their conversation, Bob starts swearing loudly, both start to fight, and Chris ends up drowning Bob (the hair under Bob's nails convince me that it wasn't an android that killed him). Immediately after, he uses the same brace to kill the J's. However, he knew that without doing anything else, by finding Bob's body the police will suspect about who killed Andrew, so he decides to frame Bob for the J's deaths by quickly strapping the brace to him.

> About the motives: Chris killed Andrew and the J's because Chris belongs to a rival gang. I think this is the reason why Chris is usually loud while he's in the bar, to spite Andrew. Bob's motive to help Chris out was financial compensation.

> I think Andrew's wife is a red herring, which is why I didn't mention her.

> Some extra notes/questions: my theory assumes that Bob had some level of discomfort with Andrew, enough to agree to kill him, but there isn't much evidence of this; alternatively, he could've really needed the money Chris was offering him, but again, not much proof. I also don't know why Chris wouldn't tell Bob that he planned to kill the J's too, or use the brace while in his presence. Maybe it's because he knew Bob would never agree otherwise, but who knows. Also, I'm not sure why the J's weren't in their room at the time, presumably because the first android scared them away.

> I agree with Donnelle's references.

I liked the story quite a bit.